# Why does my exe file not follow a specified path in the script?

Tags: python, directory, exe

So I have made an exe file that will run up to the point where it needs to open and write to a csv file, the fault is:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'P:\\myfile\\directory\\sheet.csv'
>
> [5520] Failed to execute script sheetcsv

The directory does exist, and the script executes when in debug mode or from a python shell, it only fails when in exe format.

I have also noticed that it prints `\\` between directories, this is not how it looks in my script.

One theory i have is that an exe file cannot write to a shared network drive.

I am running on windows 10, python3.7

my code is:

```
with open('P:\my\directory\sheet.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
```

Comment: Could you post the piece of code that you are using that is relevant to this error?
Very likely you have an escaping problem in your strings

Comment: @purpletentacle i have added the relevent part of my script to the question, as i say this works fine within visual stuido, python shell and as a compiled python file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change that to:

```
with open('P:/my/directory/sheet.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
```

Notice the change from `\` to `/`

Python strings consider backslashes as escaping character. You have many options:

- replace `\` with `/`
- use `\\`
- use raw literals, i.e.: `r"P:\my\directory\sheet.csv"`
- use `os.path.sep`
- use `os.path.join`
- etc..

In your case, I would say the easiest is to just replace `\` with `/` as the example I gave you.

Just as an example, try the following:

```
print("mydir\nothing\table.csv")
```

Output:

```
P:\mydir
othing  able
```

and you will see that the output is not what you initialy expect because `\n` and `\t` have been converted to special characters :)

In general, avoid using backslashes `\` in strings unless you are sure what is going on. Directories separated with `/` will be handled properly.

Comment: For sake of completeness: under etc. one common option is to use "raw" string literal `r"P:\my\directory\sheet.csv"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I added a few more.